# Runtime values for expression parameters while using ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4

In the UI of a web app I am trying to display autocomplete suggestions to the users for excel functions. This is being done using ANTLR4TS typescript library. I have a grammar like given below

```
conditionalFunction : STRING relational_op STRING;
relational_op : EQ | LT | GT | NE | LTE | GTE | IS | IS_NOT | LIKE;

EQ  : '=';
LT  : '<';
GT  : '>';
NE  : '!=';
LTE : '<=';
GTE : '>=';
```

In the UI, user selects a set of columns that are of interest to them (example : 'column1','column2'...) before defining the formulas. While providing intelli-sense of the expression, is it possible to provide users auto-suggestions for the two parameters of the expression **conditionalFunction** from the available columns list that user selected? How to do this using ANTLR4TS ?

Please note that the column names will not follow the naming convention mentioned in the example, and can be any alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code completion is not something that ANTLR does “out of the box”.  It’s easy to think that the grammar should be enough information to provide code completion.  Turns out, it’s a bit trickier than that.

However, given that you’re already using TypeScript, Have a look at antlr-c3 https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-c3

It’s not quite like you just add it and then you get code completion, but it does a very good job of providing the response data structure you need to search symbol tables, etc. and provide code completion (of course, you’ll also need to work out how to integrate with your particular editor).

ANTLR C3 will do a great deal of the hard work for you (and with ANTLRs algorithms it’s not nearly as simple as it seems on the surface).

Comment: Thank you. I just discovered that Monaco editor allows custom implementation of the  provideCompletionItems for code completion. https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.completionitemprovider.html